# first example of backwards induction?

Tags: math-history

In *Mathematics Magazine* 28(1954/55), 21-46, Richard Bellman presents a proof for the theorem which says that the geometric mean of $n$ numbers is always not greater than the arithmetic mean: the proof runs by showing that this is the case for $n=2^k$ and then by going backwards to "fill the blanks".

I am sure this is not the first case in which induction is used backwards, from a larger to a smaller number, but I cannot find an earlier example, or at least an early statement of that proof. Could someone help me?

Comment: The argument presented by Bellman is due to Cauchy, *Cours d'analyse*.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. We answer math-history questions here, right?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thanks! Would you mind put it into an answer, so that I may officially accept it?

Comment: You are welcome. I do not really know that the Cauchy proof was the first instance of backwards induction, only that (1821) he published a backwards induction proof of AM/GM, almost certainly the first to do so. There is sort of a case for Fermat's descent proof that every prime of the form $4k+1$ is of the form $x^2+y^2$ involves backwards induction.

Comment: at least for me, infinite descent is different from backwards induction, since the former - in spite of its name - is bound to be finite...